# Is there a faster way to write python outputs back to excel using xlwings in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, xlwings

I have excel file column A, B and C as inputs and then I want to do calculation in python and then return the outputs back o the excel column D and E. Is there faster way than for loop?
[image]

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def square(inputs):
    age = inputs['AGE']
    weight = inputs['WEIGHT']
    outputs = {}
    outputs['output_age_square'] = age*age
    outputs['output_weight_square'] = weight*weight
    return outputs

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\TEST.xlsx')     #connect to the daily file xlsm
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
end_row_num = sheet.range('A' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
df = sheet.range('A1'+':'+'C'+str(end_row_num)).options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False).value #read all inputs

inputs = df.to_dict('records') #inputs is a list of dicts
outputs = [square(single_input) for single_input in inputs]

for i in range(len(inputs)):
    row = 2+i
    ###########Is there faster way to return back outputs to excel cells#######
    sheet.range('D'+str(row)).value = outputs[i]['output_age_square']
    sheet.range('E'+str(row)).value = outputs[i]['output_weight_square']
```

Comment: I would say a more common approach would be to do your calculations in pandas and then export them to a xlsx file with [`df.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html?highlight=to_excel#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel), most likely this would be faster too.

Answer (score 1):

With xlwings (as with VBA), you have to assign whole arrays to the range, instead of looping through individual cells to make it fast. E.g., you can assign a DataFrame directly to the top left cell like so:

```
sheet.range('D1').value = df
```